# Transmission or not?

Tags: ford, automatic-transmission, mustang

I have a question. My 2007 ford Mustang with an automatic transmission will start up and allow you to put it in any gear, but the car will not move even though the motor revs up. Any idea what caused this. It drove normal the day before with no check engine warnings.

Comment: When you move the shifter from Park to Drive (or Reverse), do you feel it shift, or does it act like it's just ignoring the shifter?

Answer (score 3):

**Inspect your transmission shifter cable.** Make sure it is tight at both ends, as this is the most likely cause. This would leave the transmission in Park. If the cables seems tight, shift through all the positions on the selector, do this a few times, and then try D again. If it still doesn't work, try R.

**Make sure you have transmission fluid.** Use the dipstick, make sure you have enough tranny fluid. In an automatic, no fluid, tranny no go.